# Can the derived attribute (eg, age ) be present in the same table with the attribute it is derived from ( DOB)? If no then where should it be present?

Tags: database-design

I have an assignment that requires me to use particular attributes. The query that I have is. If I where to derive the attribute age from the DOB field, can the I use age as a field in my table? If not then where should I present the derived attribute age so that it can be used later?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is slightly situational based on the context of the database system / application, and there's probably merit for storing it either way (in the same table as the field it's derived from or a separate table), but in general there's nothing wrong with storing it in the same table. In most cases you'll find it makes sense and is just generally easier for maintainability.

With best practices for databases, you should avoid storing derived fields in general, when they're easily derivable, for example an `age` field in this case, as that's simply just the current date - the `D.O.B.` field. The reasoning is because it can lead to data redundancy or be error prone depending on the mechanism used to derive the field. Please note you should also avoid using special characters in field names as another best practice, but that's outside the scope of this question.

But sometimes it makes sense to store derived fields in the database (usually achievable with calculated / generated fields in most database management systems) when the logic / expression to derive them is complicated and / or performance is a concern. A data warehouse is an example database architecture where storing multiple derived fields to improve querying performance is traded at the cost of data redundancy and additional storage usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually had this kind of conversation with manglement in the past, and it always came away with them wanting to SEE the age quick and easy, without having to do the math themselves. My solution was to NEVER store a derived value in the table, but create a view that would do it for them. The table would contain the DOB, and then the view that they would select from would run the calculation when the report would be pulled.

As another person said, it could be valuable to store a derived value in a table if the calculations are having an impact on performance, but that usually doesn't come into play until you are dealing in the millions of rows at a time, or with really complex computations.